# Google Cloud pgSQL edit pg_settings

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to edit pg_settings on a Google Cloud PostgreSQL so that it'll fit my needs.

First tried `ALTER SYSTEM SET (...)`, but got

> "ERROR:  must be superuser to execute ALTER SYSTEM command"

response.

Then tried creating a superuser (despite Gcloud default user postgre be a part of cloudsqlsuperuser, it's not a superuser - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users). Couldn't find a way to do it.

Then searched another way to do it, found none.

Can you help?

PS: I'm trying that because when DB was on a shared ambient (like dreamhost simplest thing) a process of import data from csv file into the webapplication would take 1 hour, now on the GCloud (1VCPU and 3.75GB RAM - not shared) it's taking almost 10 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Cloud SQL instances are managed instances, all users created through Cloud SQL are part of the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role and it has `CREATEROLE`, `CREATEDB`, and `LOGIN` attributes. It does not have the `SUPERUSER` or `REPLICATION` attributes. See more details in [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users). Therefore, the features that require `SUPERUSER` privileges are unsupported. See more details in [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/features#differences-pg).

If you want to have a SQL database with all privileges, you can deploy a Compute Engine instance and install PostgreSQL on there. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/sql-server/creating-sql-server-instances) is a tutorial to do it. This will give you complete control over the SQL instance.

To understand what is happening with the CSV file upload, could you provide more details: the size and the data of the csv file, the environment for file updating, etc.